# AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'read'. Uses requsts and jsons

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, python-requests

Full code:

```
import requests as req
import json
Bin = int(300000)
BinMax = int(600000)
File = open("C:/Users/admin/Desktop/PS Now Generaetors/Bins.txt", 'a')

while Bin != BinMax:
    json1 = req.get("https://lookup.binlist.net/" + str(Bin))
    json2 = json1.text
    jsonout = json.loads(json2)
    country = jsonout["country"]
    cc = country["alpha2"]
    if "US" or "AT" or "BE" or "CA" or "FR" or "De" or "IE" or "JP" or "LU" or "NL" or "CH" or "GB" or "ES" or "IT" or "PT" or "NO" or "DK" or "FI" or "SE" or "PH" == cc:
        print (bin, "writed")
        File.write("\n" + str(Bin) + ";" + cc)
    Bin =+ 1
```

Full error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\PS Now Generaetors\test.py", line 3, in <module>
    json2 = json1.read()
AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'read'
```

How to fix it? Please help.

Comment: `json2 = json1.read()` That line is not in the posted code sample.  Please edit the question to include your actual code.

Comment: Josh Gordon, its full code and every string in question. I too dont understand why  error have string ```json2 = json1.read()```

Comment: Your posted code has `json2 = json1.text`, not `json2 = json1.read()`.  Also, the error message says it's on line 3, which does not match the posted code.  We can't help if you don't show us the real code you're using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use `.json()` to convert response to python dict. There's no need in `import json` usage.
2. Your country code comparison is invalid.

Try to do something like this:

```py
import requests

Bin = 300000  # no need for int()
BinMax = 600000  # no need for int()
File = open("C:/Users/admin/Desktop/PS Now Generaetors/Bins.txt", 'a')
countries = ("US", "AT", "BE", "CA", "FR", "De", "IE", "JP", "LU", "NL", "CH", "GB", "ES", "IT", "PT", "NO", "DK", "FI", "SE", "PH")

while Bin != BinMax:
    response = requests.get("https://lookup.binlist.net/" + str(Bin))
    jsonout = response.json()  # use .json() to get response as JSON
    country = jsonout["country"]
    cc = country["alpha2"]
    if cc in countries:  # previous comparison won't work as you expect
        print(bin, "written")
        File.write("\n" + str(Bin) + ";" + cc)
    Bin =+ 1
```